# Entity Framework Core 2.1.1 GroupBy Evaluating Locally

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ado.net, entity-framework-core

I've updated my C# .NET 4.7 project to use EF Core 2.1.1 (it was previously using 2.0.2) to take advantage of the new GroupBy functionality. However, I'm still seeing that the LINQ expression could not be translated and will be evaluated locally. I'm a bit stymied since my query is not at all complex. I'm using MVC .NET Core 2.0 (which, given their documentation, shouldn't be an issue.)

This is my query:

```
        var query = this.context.UserTable
            .Where(d => d.CreatedBy.Equals(this.CurrentUser.Id))
            .Where(d => d.ApplicationId.Equals(this.CurrentUser.Application.Id))
            .GroupBy(d => d.JobId)
            .ToList();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Only the `GroupBy` selecting only keys and aggregates are translated to SQL `GROUP BY`. This style of `GroupBy` query has no SQL equivalent, hence makes no sense to be performed server side - they use `ORDER BY` and do the grouping locally.

Comment: Please specify result type too. I mean you want list of what

Comment: @IvanStoev, thank you! Now that I look at it again it is obvious. My intention here was to create hierarchical data, and it makes perfect sense that can't be translated into SQL equivalent and run server side.